# Magento 2.4 Failed to load the knockout component

Tags: javascript, uicomponent, knockoutjs, phtml, knockout

Good morning, could someone help me with the error "Error loading the component "Custom_Module/js/customer-lines" that occurs to me when loading a JS knockout file, the error appears a few times, that is to say that sometimes the component is loaded

I have tried to solve the problem in many ways, but it does not work for me.

Phtml file that loads the js "app/code/Custom/Module/view/frontend/templates/lines.phtml".

[image]

JS app/code/Custom/Module/view/frontend/web/js/customer-lines.js

[image]

Thank you for your attention if you help me I will be very grateful.

Comment: It may be helpful to include the _path_ of the files that you reference.

Comment: It is understood

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that you are trying to load a phtml file.
The js component usually call a knockout template with html extension.

These files are located in web/template folder and not in templates.
Static files (like html, css and js) for each module are published on pub/static///... so js can call the html file at the same level, phtml files are not located here